# can't show headerVIew in tableVIew correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview

I create 2 custom tableViews when I use this code:

```
   UITableView *mainTableView=[[MainTableView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:mainTableView];
```

The headerView I create didn't show.

```
UITableView *mainTableView=[[MainTableView alloc]init];
self.view=mainTableView;
```

This code shows the right view. What happened to my headerView?

[image: WRONG][image: RIGHT]

UPDATE:MainTableView.m

```
+(instancetype)createMainView
{
    return [[self alloc]init];
}
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self addmainTableView];
    [self addHeadImageViewAndPageControl];
    [self addTitleLabelAndNavigationButton];
    return self;
}
#pragma mark -add view to main view
-(void)addHeadImageViewAndPageControl
{
    UIScrollView *headImageView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    headImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, yScreenWidth, yScreenHeight/3);
    headImageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    self.tableHeaderView=headImageView;
    //add pagecontroll
    UIPageControl *headPageControl=[[UIPageControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-100, yScreenHeight/3-30, yScreenWidth/3, 25)];
    headPageControl.numberOfPages=5;
    headPageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    headPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    headPageControl.currentPage=1;
    [self.tableHeaderView addSubview:headPageControl];
}
```

this is my headerView.

Comment: What header view? The code you posted makes no attempt to create or show any header view.

Comment: Provide more details buddy @rmaddy is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your code is not set frame for Tableview. Put the code below before you add tableView to self.view.

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

or

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: I'm not sure but i think `self.view` default is fit with screen. So in this case mainTableView will automatically fit with original `self.view`.